# Address bar shortcut in Firefox 4?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, firefox

In earlier versions of Firefox, I used <kbd>F6</kbd> to go the address bar. However this does not seem to work any longer and seems to switch between the tab bar and the display part. What is the new shortcut?

PS: I use the [Tab Mix Plus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_Mix_Plus) and [Vimperator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vimperator) plugins, if that matters.

Comment: Related Mozilla Support post: http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/770947

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These work in most programs that have a location bar:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
- On Windows, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

Comment: `Cmd-L` on OS X.

Comment: Ctrl + L also works on windows.

Comment: @soul: It does work on all OSes, yes. I just noted that Alt-D seems to be specific to Windows.

Answer (score 0):

To make <kbd>F6</kbd> work again, disable the "Tabs on Top" feature. Select menu *View → *Toolsbars* → *Tabs on Top* to turn it off.

---

[image]

Comment: f6 works fine for me in firefox12 with tabs on top.